# Does existing user that not update the apps still get GCM notification after I migrate to FCM?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

If I upgrade my android apps and server notification to FCM, then update it to playstore. Does old apps that not updated (because still use gcm) still get notification? Should I inform all of my user to mandatory update the apps?

Thanks

Comment: Yes i think they will still get the notifications.

Comment: Anirudh is correct, app(still using gcm) may receive notification as [FCM inherits the GCM’s core infrastructure](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq). It is recommended for your user to update your app so that you may not encounter any complication in the notification like what the [blog](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/05/google-cloud-messaging-and-firebase.html) recommend - "However, all new client side features will be added to FCM SDKs moving forward. As such, we strongly recommend that you upgrade to the FCM SDKs."

Comment: finally I've got an answer from firebase-support, unfortunately GCM client will not receive push notification from FCM server. (I post the reply from firebase-support as an answer) , thanks all

Answer (score 1):

here is the reply from firebase-support@google.com :

> Thanks for reaching out!
>
> Unfortunately, you won't be able to use Firebase APIs to send a notification directly to a target client by using the old GCM registration tokens. Registration tokens are generated by using the combination of Sender ID and API key and if those ID which belongs to GCM is different from FCM project, It will likely throw the [MismatchSenderId error](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref?hl=en-419#error-codes) (or other error listed in the doc).
>
> Hope this helps.

and the answer is No, FCM can't send push notification to GCM client.